# align ! missing } inserted

Tags: latex

I am trying to typeset the following equation in the align-evoirement

```
\begin{align}
t_2'                &= t_2 + \frac{L/C} \\
t_1'                &= t_1 + \frac{L + v\Delta t\cos\theta}{c} \\
t_2' - t_1'         &= (t_2-t_1) + \frac{L-L-v\Delta t\cos\theta}{C} \\
\Delta t'           &= \Delta t - \frac{v\Delta t \cos \theta}{c} \\
\Delta t'           &= \Delta t \left(1-\frac{v\cos\theta}{c}\right) \\
\frac{1}{\nu}       &= \frac{1}{\nu_0 \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}~\left(1-\frac{v\cos \theta {c}\right) \\
\nu                 &= \nu_0\frac{ \sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}{1-\dfrac{v\cos \theta }{c}}
\end{align}
```

But when I tried this I got the following message:

```
[45]
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.938 \end{align}
           
?
```

I copied the equations in Matcha (without the &), where it was perfectly working... I tried some things, but those did not seem to work...

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At two occasions you write `\frac{..}` without the mandatary second argument. You must write `\frac{...}{...}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
t_2'                &= t_2 + \frac{L}{C} \\
t_1'                &= t_1 + \frac{L + v\Delta t\cos\theta}{c} \\
t_2' - t_1'         &= (t_2-t_1) + \frac{L-L-v\Delta t\cos\theta}{C} \\
\Delta t'           &= \Delta t - \frac{v\Delta t \cos \theta}{c} \\
\Delta t'           &= \Delta t \left(1-\frac{v\cos\theta}{c}\right) \\
\frac{1}{\nu}       &= \frac{1}{\nu_0 \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}~\left(1-\frac{v\cos \theta}{c}\right) \\
\nu                 &= \nu_0\frac{ \sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}{1-\dfrac{v\cos \theta }{c}}
\end{align}



\end{document}
```